# Dynamically update database Entity Framework model

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm just finishing an ASP.NET website based on a pretty complex (and shared) database.

I used the Entity Framework with a database-first approach. The problem is I just learnt that two tables' structure is likely to change (new columns added from time to time). Argh !
The only good thing is that I can check for changes in another table.
Is there a way to "regenerate" the two tables'model at run time ?

Otherwise, what would you suggest ? (redesigning the database is not an option, unfortunately)

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe create a view with the columns your website use (and ensure new columns got resonable default)

Comment: if you changed in your existing table then you have to change in your code also so at a time you can keep one model inside the one `edmx` you can create another `edmx` for another work but in your case doesn't make sense i think `View` would be fine